# requests.get().text returns an empty string but the webpage displays correctly in a browser

Tags: python, https, python-requests

Here is my simple code snippet about Scrapy from [jd-comment](https://club.jd.com/comment/productPageComments.action?productId=100002967883&score=0&sortType=5&page=72&pageSize=10&isShadowSku=0&rid=0&fold=1).

```py
import requests
url = 'https://club.jd.com/comment/productPageComments.action?productId=100002967883&score=0&sortType=5&page=72&pageSize=10&isShadowSku=0&rid=0&fold=1'
header = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' }
response = requests.get(url = url, headers = header}
data = response.json()
```

The error message:

```
File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

After debug I got: **`response.text=''`**
From [requests's official document](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

> For example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response contains invalid JSON, attempting r.json() raises requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError.

Here are what ChatGPT3 told me:

> 1. Make sure that the URL you are using is correct and that it returns data when you access it from your browser.
> 2. Check if the website requires any headers or cookies to be set in order to access the data. You can try setting the same headers and cookies in your Python script.
> 3. Some websites use JavaScript to load data dynamically. In this case, you may need to use a tool like Selenium to simulate a browser and load the data.
> 4. It's possible that the website is blocking your requests. You can try adding a delay between requests or using a proxy to avoid being detected as a bot.

And what I tried:

1. The URl is correct and it displays correctly in my chrome/safari on Mac.
   [image: screenshot]
2. I tried same 'user-agent' as headers shown in chrome develop but still not working.
3. I'm not sure about if this website is loaded by javascript dynamically.
   What I can provide:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.example.com')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
html = driver.page_source
print(html)
driver.quit()
```

output:

```
# what does this mean?
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

4. I'am using system proxy via ClashX -- not working and delivering 'proxies' as params to get() -- not working.

**Anyway, is there anyone who can provid any ideas about what the hell is going on? I'd be appreciated for you help!**

Comment: You can determine what's loaded by JS by looking at the "Sources" tab. "Elements" shows you the current, loaded state of the page. "Sources" shows you what was sent to your browser; which is more relevant to you here.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that there is no evidence showing that it is loaded by JS. But why it returned empty?

Comment: What does this have to do with scrapy? Also the page that you linked to is completely blank

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your comment. It is just a code snippet during learning scrapy.  And the link worked for me just like the screenshot above.(For your occasion, possibly due to firewall block from CN gov)

Comment: `possibly due to firewall block from CN gov` - You just answered your own question. Your scraper is being blocked. Blocked people get blank pages. Your scraper returns blank pages... what could possibly be the problem? </sarc>